# Can I use an old home directory in my new Ubuntu installation?

Tags: installation, 12.10, home-directory

I've installed Ubuntu 12.10 and I did somethings wrong (things that do not allow me to boot my system any more), when I installed it for the first time I used the following table of partition: one for the user files `/home` and one for every thing else (`/`).

So, I'd like to know if I can install (again) the Ubuntu 12.10 and use this old `/home` directory, can I?

Answer (score 3):

You most certainly can. I've been doing that for a while now.

During installation, you should make sure that you select the old home partition to be used as "home" and that you do not format it. That is basically all there is to it; that's how you use your old home partition.

Now, because you mentioned you did some things wrong, you will probably want to delete your old settings as well. Most (all? Any gurus here to confirm?) of these are stored in the dot folders and files (e.g. `/home/zignd/.filezilla/` or `/home/zignd/.config/`). By moving all the dot folders and files away from `/home/zignd/` to for example `/home/zignd/backup-dotfiles` you can reset all the settings. By moving instead of removing you can restore the settings you'd want. For example, the `.filezilla` folder might contain some settings you can still use and is most likely not responsible for the issues you have.

Comment: +1, because; you mentioned the remotion of dot files/directories, but you should also recommend to delete just the dot files/directories related to programs the user installed, because there are some dot files/directories that were generated by the system when it was installed. (Note: I don't know if I'm really correct about it) :)

Comment: Right. But if the configuration is messed up (assuming you do not know WHERE the problem), you likely want to move all the dot files and folders. That way, the new installation will just reset the entire configuration to the system defaults (still looking for a guru to confirm :)

Answer (score 0):

There'll be no problem with it. You can use old `/home` directory for new installation.